# Plone2pdf Add-on , portalTransform exception : ITransform

Tags: python, plone

Trying to setup plone2pdf in Plone 4. I have downloaded the Plone2pdf archive, extracted it and placed it under the products directory of my instance. I have restarted the instance, by ./bin/instance fg.

Now, I can see the Plone2pdf in the available add-ons page. but, when I click on the activate button it throws an error as follows

```
2011-11-16 00:58:28 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1321385308.830.136673010237
http://10.20.254.20:8090/iopextech/portal_quickinstaller/installProducts
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 575, in installProducts
Module Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.QuickInstallerTool, line 498, in installProduct
- __traceback_info__: ('Plone2Pdf',)
Module Products.ExternalMethod.ExternalMethod, line 234, in __call__
- __traceback_info__: ((<PloneSite at /iopextech>,), {'reinstall': False}, (False,))
Module /usr/local/Plone/test/products/Plone2Pdf/Extensions/Install.py, line 20, in install
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 323, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
- __traceback_info__: profile-Products.Plone2Pdf:default
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1080, in _runImportStepsFromContext
Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 994, in _doRunImportStep
- __traceback_info__: pdf-transforms-various
Module Products.Plone2Pdf.setuphandlers, line 34, in setupPortalTransforms
Module Products.Plone2Pdf.setuphandlers, line 21, in installPdfTransform
Module Products.PortalTransforms.TransformEngine, line 485, in manage_addTransform
Module Products.PortalTransforms.Transform, line 100, in __init__
Module Products.PortalTransforms.Transform, line 125, in _tr_init
- __traceback_info__: ('Products.Plone2Pdf.html_to_pdf',)
TransformException: Invalid transform : ITransform is not implemented byProducts.Plone2Pdf.html_to_pdf.html_to_pdf
```

The version of Plone2pdf is 0.4.3. What could be the problem ? is Plone2pdf compliant with Plone 4, because the Plone2pdf release which I downloaded was tested only with Plone 3. But the download page says, Use buildout to install if installing on Plone 3 or higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install an add-on product you should always first check the project page:

http://plone.org/products/plone2pdf

to verify any dependency or limitations. In this specific instance, the developer says that the product is compatible with Plone <= 3. In these case, unless you know exactly what you are doing and unless you are prepared for some debug, you should just find another product that is declared to be compatible with Plone 4. Btw installing product in the Products directory is an old way for installing product, take a look [here](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/add-ons/installing) a more up to date way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

Let me explain what I am trying to accomplish, I have seen somewhere in a portal they have a pdf icon next to print and full screen view icon. upon clicking that it lets the user to download the content as pdf. how can I achieve that ? are there any well known ways of doing that ?

Comment: There's a products named "collective.sendaspdf" (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sendaspdf) that does exactly that job and it's plone4 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This mean this addon is not compatible with Plone4 and need to be udpated to support changes related to transform.

documentation: http://plone.org/documentation/kb/portal-transforms/transforms